# SOAPUI PRO Transfer get Message value into another suite

Tags: soapui

Im new to SOAPUI Pro and  need to transfer the the Id feild value from a GET method in suite1 to POST method in suite2.
Which are the methods should i use to do this. Thanks for help..

Comment: A possible way to do so is to put this properties in a project level which is a shared context for all your `testSuites`. How to do it? Depends, there are several way to do so... however your question is really broad, if you provide more details I could be more specific `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your test is separated in 2 suites, i think it's not good.

To answer your question: you can write your properties in a file withva datasource/datasinkor use a 'library' which is another suite with a groovy script. In this groovy, you can create a class to access a properties step and you can reuse some properties
Or you can directly put the properties in the suite properties but it's a bad idea. It is unreadable